# Slow Finder - Caused by external disks?

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, hard-drive, time-machine, backup

I've been finding Finder slow on my brand new Retina MacBook Pro.

I've got two external disks connected to my Mac most of the time. One is a Time Machine backup, the other is a Clone, also for backup. They spin down when not in use which is great. However, I've noticed that Finder is slow to respond. When I access Finder, I hear them spin up and then it is responsive.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: Did you try ejecting/unplugging them to see whether Finder gets faster then?

Comment: Same issue. Did you find a resolution? Jaime's answer below didn't work for me, that option was already deselected.

Answer (score 1):

You can try unchecking "Put the hard disk(s) to sleep when possible" on System Preferences > Energy Saver ([source](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3305000?tstart=0)).

There's also an app that says it will give more detailed control called (appropriately) "Keep Drive Spinning". 
[Here is a link to the developer site](http://jon.stovell.info/software/), the app sends you to macupdate for the download –be careful with bundled software on the "install now" link. I have not tried it myself.